# Error setting mysql primary key field with preparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

This is my code for inserting a row. The columns are: primary id, name, and artist.

Am I passing the primary id correctly because it keeps on giving me an error? It is set to one and it increments every time a row is added.

```
try {
    //Database
    String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(lyrics1_id, name, artist) values(?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(2, nameOfSong.getText()); // set input parameter 2
    statement.setString(3, artist.getText()); 
    statement.setLong(i, i);
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lyrics1");
    while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
    statement.execute();
    rs.close();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
    i++;

} catch (SQLException insertException) {
    displaySQLError(insertException);
}
```

The error is:

```
SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1 SQLState: 07001 VendorError: 0
```

Comment: SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

SQLState:     07001

VendorError:  0

Comment: String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) values(?, ?)";
                 PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                 statement.setString(1, nameOfSong.getText()); // set input parameter 2
                 statement.setString(2, artist.getText()); 
                 ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lyrics1");

Comment: SQLException: Field 'lyrics1_id' doesn't have a default value

SQLState:     HY000

VendorError:  1364

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post updates in comments.

Answer (score 4):

If your primary key is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which it sounds like it is, you do not pass it with the `INSERT` statement, it is handled automatically for you.  This would be what you want to do:

```
INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist)
VALUES(?, ?)
```

Comment: It only gives an error if the id already exists (ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '15' for key 1)

Answer (score 3):

(This assumes your primary key *isn't* `AUTO_INCREMENT` and that you're passing it for a reason.)

I think you have a simple typo:

```
statement.setLong(i, i);
```

should probably be

```
statement.setLong(1, i);
//                ^-- 1, not i
```

Being an old fuddy-duddy, I'd also probably move that statement above the other two so you're doing them in order.

Comment: @how do you set it to autoincrement

Comment: @JadJ: By adding that modifier to the column definition; [details in the manaul](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html). But you're not required to make it `AUTO_INCREMENT` if you don't want to, it's just a very common use-case if the primary key is just an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 2):

If you have auto_increment in primary key:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) values(?, ?)";
```

Comment: String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) values(?, ?)"; PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query); statement.setString(1, nameOfSong.getText()); // set input parameter 2 statement.setString(2, artist.getText()); ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lyrics1")

Comment: but now it gives me this error...SQLException: Field 'lyrics1_id' doesn't have a default value SQLState: HY000 VendorError: 1364

Comment: @JadJ: So that means it's not `AUTO_INCREMENT`. That's fine, primary keys don't *have* to be, it's just a very common use case for them.

Comment: @JadJ how do you set it to autoincrement?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the quotes when inserting a TEXT or VARCHAR value, like "INSERT INTO lyrics1(lyrics1_id, name, artist) VALUES ("id","name","artist").

Also, if the key is auto-incremental, do not pass it, the SQL will do it by itself. The query should then be "INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) VALUES ("name","artist")."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should have a ; in the string at the end like so:

String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(lyrics1_id, name, artist) values(?, ?, ?)";

however, it may work anyway.

Comment: E.g., he *doesn't* have a `;` in the SQL code, note how it's outside the quotes. (It wouldn't matter if he did, MySQL doesn't care, but you wouldn't want to do it...)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the line you setting a value for primary key:

```
statement.setLong(i, i);
```

Here, did you see the first argument, it is `i` instead of `1`. So it has to be changed to

```
statement.setLong(1, i);
```

But, if you ran the program for a second time, if the value of your `i` is initialized to a constant, you will get a primary key violation exception. Since, you are using MySQL, and if you used `AUTO_INCREMENT` for primary key column, then you can avoid that field in `INSERT` query. MySQL will automatically assign a value for the field. So you may use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) values(?, ?)
```